# Issue with Password and Keys app on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, seahorse

Password and keys app comes pre installed with ubuntu 20.04 and I've come across a peculiar situation that I could use some help with.

I've noticed that when I access the "login" section in Password and Keys, I see two entries named "Chrome Safe Storage" and "Chrome Safe Storage Control," both with associated passwords. However, I haven't manually added any passwords to these entries myself.

My primary concern is determining the origin of these entries. How did these "Chrome Safe Storage" entries get added, and who might have initiated this?

Additionally, I've observed that when I save a password within the Chrome browser, it doesn't seem to automatically integrate with the "Password and Keys" application. This behavior raises questions about potential security implications.

Could someone kindly provide insights into these matters? Am I facing any security risks or potential vulnerabilities due to these occurrences?

I have added screenshot here of the app for better understanding

[image: photo]
[image]
[image]